# Express.js : get inserted Id with nested queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have mysql nested queries in my express.js app and i need to get the inserted id of all queries but i got only insertId of the global query .. i got this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined

in line :

> vid = results.insertId

my code :

```js
      let vid="" 
 
      con.query('INSERT INTO table1 SET ....', function(err, results, fields) {
                
                let res1=results.insertId

                con.query("insert into table2 ... res1='" + res1 + "'",
                    function(err0, results, fields) {
                        vid = results.insertId

                        if (err0) {
                            console.log( err0)

                        }
                    })

               
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error saving record',
                    err: err
                });

            }
            return res.json({
                message: 'saved',
                id: results.insertId,
                vid: vid
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the return `res.json` into the "deepest" callback

```
      let vid="" 
 
      con.query('INSERT INTO table1 SET ....', function(err, results, fields) {
                
                let res1=results.insertId

                con.query("insert into table2 ... res1='" + res1 + "'",
                    function(err0, results, fields) {
                        vid = results.insertId

                        if (err0) {
                            console.log( err0)

                        }

                        // ======= MOVED HERE ========
                        return res.json({
                            message: 'saved',
                            id: res1,
                            vid: vid
                        });
                    })

               
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error saving record',
                    err: err
                });

            }
        })
```